# Where are google app engine logs of exited (nodejs) application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My google app engine nodejs app failed

In Logs viewer:

```
Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to 
stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated
```

It since has been restarted on next HTTP request.

Where/How do I find stdout/stderr of failed container for post-mortem analysis

Logs:

Quitting on terminated signal:

```
{
  "textPayload": "[start] 2020/03/04 07:55:39.816933 Quitting on terminated signal",
  "insertId": "5e5f5efb000c7d312b1f44c8",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "us-east1-2",
      "project_id": "dev-keep-md",
      "version_id": "20200303t212902"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:39.818481Z",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117ccb894ade35709af1833ec830a1bb062e757cd255b73cdc295876d8ceda3377"
  },
  "logName": "projects/dev-keep-md/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fgoogle_init.log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:39.824498567Z"
}
```

then

Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated

```
{
  "textPayload": "[start] 2020/03/04 07:55:40.018902 Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated",
  "insertId": "5e5f5efc00004b70f29f00c9",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "version_id": "20200303t212902",
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "us-east1-2",
      "project_id": "dev-keep-md"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:40.019312Z",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117ccb894ade35709af1833ec830a1bb062e757cd255b73cdc295876d8ceda3377"
  },
  "logName": "projects/dev-keep-md/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fgoogle_init.log",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:40.158203987Z"
}
```

then

Container called exit(1).

```
{
  "textPayload": "Container called exit(1).",
  "insertId": "5e5f5efc000661ed4ffa83fc",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "dev-keep-md",
      "version_id": "20200303t212902",
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "us-east1-2"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:40.418038958Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117ccb894ade35709af1833ec830a1bb062e757cd255b73cdc295876d8ceda3377"
  },
  "logName": "projects/dev-keep-md/logs/varlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-03-04T07:55:40.420598849Z"
}
```

Comment: if you have configured everything correctly you should have the logs in stackdriver

Answer (score 0):

The logs should be on Stackdriver as mentioned on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/writing-application-logs),  if you need to have more information that what currently is being written, you can write it with `console.log()` or `console.error()` so that can debug it easier.

Hope you find this useful.